# Disable Shortcode usage for certain user roles

Tags: wordpress, user-roles

I have a guest posting plugin on my Wordpress site and want to disable usage of shortcodes for certain users roles (subscribers for example). I need this for security reasons mostly.

Comment: To clarify:  do you want to prevent these users from inserting shortcodes into posts / pages they write?  Or do you want to prevent these shortcodes from being used when rendering posts / pages they view?

Comment: I am not quite sure.. I think second - prevent shortcodes from extracting. So user can write shortcode or something shortcode-looking like [some_text], but it will not be executed. So shortcode will be like just text.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that you have shortcode,

```
function myshortcode(){

$user = wp_get_current_user();
if ( !in_array( 'author', (array) $user->roles ) ) {
    //Run shortcode
}

}

add_shortcode('myshortcode','myshortcode');
```

Comment: Sorry if I am just misunderstanding you, but are you shure this is the right code which I needed? Because by looking at it it seems like it`s not.

Comment: then what actully want to do??

Comment: yes,as iunderstand this  check user role if its not in role then run

Comment: I want to disable all shortcodes for certain user role. If user in category "subscriber", he wont be able to use any shortcodes - this what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`strip_shortcodes()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/strip_shortcodes) function, you can use it as a filter to strip shortcodes from your desired content:

```
function example_remove_shortcode( $content ) {
  $content = strip_shortcodes( $content );
  return $content;
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'example_remove_shortcode' );
```

or

```
echo strip_shortcodes( $my_customly_created_content );
```

in where you want to show the content.

Comment: If you wrap your second line in a conditional that checks the current user role then that would probably answer the OP's question.

Comment: @Dre that's right but i wasn't quite sure where he wants to use this. I'll edit the answer