# Strip shortcodes for all user roles except administrator

Tags: wordpress, user-roles, wordpress-shortcode

I'm looking for a solution that will strip shortcodes for all wordpress user roles except administrator and which ever role i select. A solution similar to the one on the below link, It was never confirmed to work and i don't know which one works.

[Disable Shortcode usage for certain user roles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40979291/disable-shortcode-usage-for-certain-user-roles)

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You should combine both answers:

```
function remove_shortcode_for_user_roles( $content ) {
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    if ( in_array( 'administrator', (array) $user->roles ) == false &&
        in_array( 'other_role', (array) $user->roles ) == false ) {
        $content = strip_shortcodes( $content );
    }

    return $content;
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'remove_shortcode_for_user_roles' );
```

"other_role" would be that other role you also want to exclude from the shortcode stripping.

Comment: That definitely did the trick, But subscribers cannot no longer post from the frontend because the shortcode that renders the form is gone too. How do i use the above code to just remove a specific shortcode or a list of specific shortcodes?

Comment: In that case you could use **preg_replace** to remove specific shortcodes from the content. Something like: `$content = preg_replace( '/\[video(.*?)\]/s' , '' , $content );`

Comment: It seems like i'm looking for the wrong solution to my problem. I use a frontend blogging plugin called frontier post, Under advanced settings, It has an option to select the post types that you don't want to be able to use shortcodes and only recommends the use of shortcodes on page post type. It used to work fine but now shortcodes are showing up for posts published through the plugin by guest bloggers. What i really need is the ability to stop all other user roles except administrator from utilizing shortcodes.

Comment: Stripping shortcodes has the effect that, When a user with the subscriber role views the content that has a shortcode that is only set to render for admins only, The shortcode is stripped and no content shows up, Giving me a problem of not being able to display to my users any post that has a shortcode that i restricted them from utilizing when posting. I want the shortcode to show up when they view a page or post with the shortcode on it but not be able to use any shortcodes on their post because of their user role. Any suggestion will be a great help.

Comment: Hi victor, I think disabling the usage of shortcodes on the post post type is much more ideal, My users would have access to all the content that is rendered through shortcodes because all of it is in pages and not posts and still not able to use shortcodes because they only have access to 'post' post type. How do i use your first code with the edition of choosing to strip shortcodes only on posts?

Comment: Hey @user11374658, you can use [is_singular](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_single/) to determine if the current page is of a certain post type or [get_post_type](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_type/), which retrieves the post type of the current post or of a given post.